# Order by Month-year in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with following sample output;

```
Act_ID  |  STATUS  | Year-Month
123     |  a       | 2020-Dec
120     |  a       | 2020-May
124     |   b      | 2021-Feb
```

Is it possible to order it as per time; we want the following output;

**Desired Output**

```
Act_ID  |  STATUS  | Year-Month
120     |  a       | 2020-May
123     |  a       | 2020-Dec
124     |   b      | 2021-Feb
```

But when we try to order by this column, it is sorting it alphabetically.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY Year-Month;
```

**Actual Output**

```
Act_ID  |  STATUS  | Year-Month
123     |  a       | 2020-Dec
124     |  b       | 2021-Feb
120     |   a      | 2020-May
```

Comment: How can 2021 come between two 2020 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the value to a date:

```
order by to_date(year_month, 'YYYY-MON')
```